# fadeIn() function in JQuery not working

Tags: jquery, fadein

Has there been a change in the `fadeIn()` method between 1.6.2 and 1.12.2?

I'm learning JQuery. The book I'm using is old enough that the version at the time was 1.6.2 but I'm using 1.12.2.

I'm trying to use the `fadeIn()` function. I'm trying to get a photo to fade in and out. The photo shows up but it doesn't fade in like it's supposed to and after reviewing the code several times I can say it's exactly the same as the example code except for the JQuery version.

Any ideas?

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Furry Friends Campaign</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my_style1.css"> </head>

  <body>
    <div id="clickMe">Show me the furry friend of the day</div>
    <div id="picframe"> <img src="E:/Head First JQuery/ch01/Begin/images/furry_friend.jpg"> </div>
    <script src="e:/scripts/jQuery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#clickMe").click(function() {
          $("img").fadeIn(1000);
          $("#picframe").slideToggle("slow");
        });
      });

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

here's the CSS:

```
#clickMe {
    background: #D8B36E;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 205px;
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
#picframe {
    background: #D8B36E;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 205px;
    display: none;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code or provide a public URL?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community. Please include a [mcve] to your question. Without it, it is nearly impossible to know *exactly* where the issue lies.

Comment: The simplest way to check would be to temporarily use jQuery 1.6.2 instead, and if it works with that you'll know that something has changed in jQuery. If it doesn't work with that either,  the problem is somewhere in your code. I assume you've looked at the browser's Javascript console and confirmed that the code doesn't throw any errors?

Comment: Actually, I'm just trying to get the photo to fade in (not out).

Comment: Thanks, Juhana. I'm trying that now. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Cyberbit, I'll do that if Juhana's suggestion doesn't work.

Comment: <html>
<head> 
 <title>Furry Friends Campaign</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my_style1.css"> 
</head>
<body>
 <div id="clickMe">Show me the furry friend of the day</div>
 <div id="picframe">
  <img src="E:/Head First JQuery/ch01/Begin/images/furry_friend.jpg">
 </div>
 <script src="e:/scripts/jQuery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#clickMe").click(function() {
    $("img").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#picframe").slideToggle("slow");
       
   });
  }); 
 </script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Ok. That didn't go through as planned. I'm a newbie. Any pointers on how to include a properly formatted code?

Comment: Add the code to the question, not the comments section (using the edit button/link) - then remove the comments

Comment: I edited the answer for your w/ the code.

Comment: Ochi: Thanks. I'll keep that in mind. I originally asked a friend of mine at work about the issue. He was the one who recommended Stack. I probably should have done some research before jumping in. Now I'm trying to get used to this. It's like sending a guy with a BB gun to Normandy alone on June 6, 1944. Little problematic.

Comment: @H.Neal to address people so that they get messages in their inbox, add a @ tag before their name and then write their name. You will usually be prompted once you write the first letter or 2. Otherwise they won't see the messages unless they revisit the question! Just a tip!

Comment: @Rachel Gallen Thanks for that. I was wondering if I was doing that wrong. Looks like I have a lot to learn about Stackoverflow. And I thought programming languages could be challenging. Yikes!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the jQuery reference API? Here is a link that may help you get a better understanding of how `fadeIn()` works. http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Try this - https://jsfiddle.net/breezy/7dn6tm3h/

jS

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('img').fadeIn(1000);
    });
```

CSS

```
img {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code into your answer. Links can be unavailable at any given time making the question/answers
incomplete and, thus, useless to other members of the community.

Comment: Bryan Barrera: I saw that reference earlier. I didn't see anything helpful there. As for the code sample you sent. That's what I have with the exception of double quotes instead of single.

Comment: You may have your code running before jQuery is loaded, do you see any errors inside your console? @H.Neal

Comment: Bryan B: No. everything looks ok (not that i'm an expert, obviously). The first line of the JQuery is $(document).ready(function ...

Comment: In the end this isn't a critical thing for me. Like I said before, I'm just starting to learn JQuery but I'd like to know why it's misbehaving.

Comment: Bryan B: Now I don't know if this makes any difference but the img element is actually inside a div element that gets the css telling the image not only to not display immediately when the page loads but also to fade in. That's the way the example code has it and there is downloadable code with the completed version they did and it works fine. Again, the only difference is the JQuery version. Weird.

Comment: what browser are you using? make sure that the jquery library is being loaded. have you tried to use a cdn library rather than a local library? try to replace your jquery library w/ this `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` - do you see any errors in your browser console ? @H.Neal

Comment: @Bryan Barrera Hey, thanks again for your help on this. By now I'm sure you've seen my answer to my own problem posted. I have a nasty tendency to miss the tiniest detail but in the past I've been pretty good at figuring out what was wrong (granted, it took a little time). Well, it's working now so I'll keep on plugging. Maybe one day (hopefully really soon) I'll have a knowledge base similar to what the people here seem to have. It's impressive.

Comment: @Bryan Barrera I think I spoke too soon. Like my answer post said, everything was working just fine. Then I decided to play a little and changed the number of milliseconds in the argument for the fadeIn. That's the ONLY thing I touched and it's back to not fading. Strange. Oh, well. I'm not going to go crazy over this. The way I figure it, I got it to work before. But if you happen to have an idea of why a simple change to the time argument made the fadeIn function quit working I'm all ears. Not a huge priority, though.

Comment: did you add the numbers within `('1000')` marks or none? @H.Neal